# How to alter "grep" colour scheme on Windows-10 Ubuntu WSL app

Tags: linux, windows-10, colors, windows-subsystem-for-linux, grep

I'd like to alter the colour scheme of my `grep` results on my Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL, Ubuntu app on a Windows-10 computer).

My `.bashrc` file contains the following entry:

```
alias grep='grep --color=auto'
```

Both environment variables `GREP_COLOR` and `GREP_COLORS` are empty:

```
Prompt> echo $GREP_COLOR

Prompt> echo $GREP_COLORS

=> two times an empty result.
```

My `grep` version:

```
Prompt> grep --version
grep (GNU grep) 3.4
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

The reason for this question is that the `grep "text" *` gives following results:

```
file1.txt : here is text
file2.txt : here is text too
```

The names of the files (file1.txt and file2.txt) both are in purple, which is not easy to see against a black background:

[image: screenshot]

Does anybody know how to do this?

Comment: Answered here: [command line - Modifying the color of grep - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1042234/modifying-the-color-of-grep)

Comment: @DavidPostill: pardon my ignorance, but I don't get it: I have been doing `GREP_COLORS='ms=04;27'` and `GREP_COLOR='ms=04;27'` (without exporting, I prefer those things not to be saved yet), but my `grep` still looks the same. In top of that, the mentioned answer does not mention how to distinguish filenames and find results, like (file1.txt, file2.txt and "This is text" and "This is text too").

Comment: @DavidPostill: after using `export ...` I see a find result being changed, but no filename.

Comment: @DavidPostill Oddly, *not* the answer to this particular question (I thought it was as well at first).  The Ask Ubuntu question is about changing the color of the matched text substring, but this one is about changing the filename color, which the other question doesn't cover.  While I'm sure there's a version of this question on either Ask Ubuntu or Unix & Linux, I'll just add it here.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds It does (indirectly) "`fn=35` -   SGR substring for file names prefixing any content line. The default is a magenta text foreground over the terminal’s default background."

Comment: See https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#index-GREP_005fCOLORS-environment-variable

Comment: @Dominique Read it again carefully. You need to set the `fn` values

Comment: @DavidPostill Agreed, but unless I'm missing something, I don't see `fn` mentioned anywhere in *that* question other than the "defaults" line.

Comment: @DavidPostill Oh, I see what you mean, "indirectly" by mentioning the manual.  Yes, that's fair -- A `man grep` covers it also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the *filename* color, modify the `fn` value in the following line:

```
export GREP_COLORS='ms=01;31:mc=01;31:sl=:cx=:fn=35:ln=32:bn=32:se=36'
```

Per the color-charts mentioned in the [Ask Ubuntu post](https://askubuntu.com/a/1042242/1165986) that @DavidPostill linked in the comments.

For instance:

```
export GREP_COLORS='ms=01;31:mc=01;31:sl=:cx=:fn=31:ln=32:bn=32:se=36'
```

Will change the filename to red.

Also, from your comment:

> without exporting, I prefer those things not to be saved yet

That's not quite how `export` works.  `export`ing a variable in the shell (Bash, most likely, in your case) means that any subprocess that you launch from *that* shell instance will receive the exported value.  Since `grep` is a subprocess, it needs the variable to be `export`ed in order to get the updated value.  If you don't `export` the value, then it is local to your shell only, and `grep` will not see it, even when launched from Bash.

Once the shell exits, however, the `export`ed value is *not* saved.

To save the value permanently, as the linked post mentions at the end, you'll need to add the `export GREP_COLORS=...` command to your `~/.bashrc`.